# Get an IIS IP address in string format from Get-WebBinding in Powershell

Tags: powershell, iis

I am trying to retrieve the IP address of a website that I am referencing via the ID (vs. the name).  The best way I can figure out to do it is using a regex on the "bindingInformation" property going up to the first colon as below...

```
$siteID = "22"
$website = Get-Website | Where { $_.ID -eq $siteID }
$iP = Get-WebBinding $website.name | Where { $_.bindingInformation -match "/[^:]*/" }
```

However it doesn't seem to be populating the $iP variable?

As I step through I get this:

```
PS IIS:\sites> Get-WebBinding $website.name

protocol  bindingInformation                                                                        
-------- ------------------                                                                        
http      10.206.138.131:80:                                                                        
http      10.206.138.131:80:dev1.RESERVED22                                                         
http      10.206.138.131:80:dev1.www.RESERVED22
```

I guess what I'm not sure about is how to convert the $_.bindingInformation 
into a string format variable?  Pretty new to Powershell so sorry if this seems simple.  I need the $IP variable to be "10.206.138.131" in this example... Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `Select-Object -ExpandProperty bindingInformation` to grab just the `bindingInformation` property value:

```
PS C:\> Get-WebBinding "sitename" |Select-Object -ExpandProperty bindingInformation
10.206.138.131:80:
10.206.138.131:80:dev1.RESERVED22
10.206.138.131:80:dev1.www.RESERVED22
```

Now, since each binding string is in the form:

```
[IP]:[Port]:[Hostname]
```

We can use the `-split` operator to split it into 3 and just grab the first one:

```
PS C:\> $Bindings = Get-WebBinding "sitename" |Select-Object -ExpandProperty bindingInformation
PS C:\> $Bindings | ForEach-Object { @($_ -split ':')[0] }
10.206.138.131
10.206.138.131
10.206.138.131
```

Finally, you can use `Sort-Object -Unique` to remove all duplicates:

```
PS C:\> $Bindings = Get-WebBinding "sitename" |Select-Object -ExpandProperty bindingInformation
PS C:\> $IPs = $Bindings | ForEach-Object { @($_ -split ':')[0] }
PS C:\> $IPs = @($IPs |Sort-Object -Unique)
```

The `$IPs` variable is now an array containing all the distinct IP addresses used for bindings, in your case just a single one:

```
PS C:\> $IPs
10.206.138.131
```

Comment: Perfect!  Thank you so much. I wasn't aware of the -split operator nor the -unique operator.  So much to learn!  Thank you again Mathias - you saved my day..  :)  One question, what does the [0] mean in:
    { @($_ -split ':')[0] }

Comment: Glad to be able to help - just to be clear, `-split` is an *operator*, (like `+`, `=`, `-as` etc.) whereas `Unique` is a *parameter* to the `Sort-Object` cmdlet :-)

Comment: got it!  Thank you again!  This is working perfectly.  :)

Comment: `@()` results in an array, and `[$x]` means that we want the array item at index `$x`, so for example `@(2,3,4)[0]` results in `2`

Comment: Just a follow-up, all these years later. This may not work properly for IPv6. That shows up with the format: `[2023:0:34a2:52f8:71:1815:9320:3d2c]:613:mytest.local`